# Wordpress upload theme

Tags: wordpress

I was trying to install wordpres on my local computer. However, when I try to upload a theme or install some plugin using the web interface. It always prompts me to enter FTP credentials. I checked online, and it seems that ftp credentials is not necessary for uploading. I set the permissions for all directorieos and files under wp-content to be 777, but the problem is still there. And this Word press is a fresh installation on ubuntu 14.04( running in a VM) and newest wordpress.

Comment: No luck on the common solutions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I got this issue before some time wordpress ask ftp detail when I was trying to install new plugin and get resolved by adding this code in my wp-config file.

define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct');

Comment: It works for the uploading now ! But it still gives me an error saying Could not create directory.

Comment: Thanks!! However, I don't think my ubuntu has this apache user. But setting both the user and the group to be www-data works now!!

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to `wp-config.php` :

```
add_filter('filesystem_method', create_function('$a', 'return "direct";' ));
define( 'FS_CHMOD_DIR', 0751 );
```

Comment: After adding these two lines, wordpress does not even loaded to the browser. Browser could only presents an empty page. Wierd.

Comment: @user3354832 active the debug mode to see where is the problem.